# How to multiply std::vector<int> by int where vector's each element should be one digit?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, std, multiplication

I have a class, call it 'BigNumber', which has a vector v field.
Each element should be one digit.
I want to implement a method to multiply this vector by an integer, but also keep elements one digit.
E.g: <7,6> * 50 = <3,8,0,0>
The vector represents a number, stored in this way. 
 In my example, <7,6> is equal to 76, and <3,8,0,0> is 3800.

I tried the following, but this isn't good (however it works), and not the actual solution for the problem.

```
   //int num, BigNumber bn
    if (num > 0)
  {
    int value = 0, curr = 1;
    for (int i = bn.getBigNumber().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      value += bn.getBigNumber().at(i) * num * curr;
      curr *= 10;
    }
    bn.setBigNumber(value); //this shouldn't be here
    return bn;
  }
```

The expected algortithm is multiply the vector itself, not with a variable what I convert to this BigNumber.

The way I set Integer to BigNumber:

```
void BigNumber::setBigNumber(int num)
{
  if (num > 0)
  {
    bigNum.clear();
    while (num != 0)
    {
      bigNum.push_back(num % 10);
      num = (num - (num % 10)) / 10;
    }
    std::reverse(bigNum.begin(), bigNum.end());
  }
  else
  {
    throw TOOSMALL;
  }
};
```

The method I want to implement:

```
//class BigNumber{private: vector<int> bigNum; ... }
void BigNumber::multiplyBigNumber(BigNumber bn, int num)
{
  if (num > 0)
  {
    //bn.bigNum * num
  }
  else
  {
    throw TOOSMALL;
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure about your question...my understanding is check condition 0 to 9 before inserting into vector

Comment: so, I have the vector, which is already containing element, e.g. [1,2,3,4,5]. And when I call tha multiply method within main() like mulBigNum(bn,10), I want to change the vector's values itself. So I don't need to insert anything, just multiply these. My bad, forgot an important thing, update my question.

Comment: If an `int` can represent all values stored in the "big number" vector, why not just use an `int` ? Why add the complexity ?

Comment: It's a part of a school project, and the reason is that I can store larger numbers in this, than one integer.

Comment: If I want to multiply INT_MAX with INT_MAX and print the value to the screen, then I can use this class.

Comment: Does the LSB of the "big number"corresponds to index 0 of the vector ? It would be easier that it is the case, as the number of digits can be increased after the multiplication

Comment: What if you store the vector with the ones place in the first index so that you can read the numbers the other way around.  that would make arithmetic easier.

Comment: Most straightforward would probably be to implement [long multiplication](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongMultiplication.html). Far from the most efficient though.

Comment: What do you mean by "The expected algortithm is multiply the vector itself"?

Comment: You already know how to do this. You learned long multiplication when you were a child. Now all you have to do is write the code for long multiplication. Convert your integer into another BigNumber (I assume you have the code for that already, if not then it's not hard to write), and then multiply your two BigNumbers together using long multiplication.

Comment: Sorry everyone for not answering so far, I tried all these things, and not just write the code, but fully understand how it works. Long multiplication was the solution for the problem (or at least some part of it). Thanks very much for all the helpful comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is for a school project, I don't want to just write the code for you. So here's a hint.

Let's say you give me the number 1234 --- and I choose to store each digit in a vector *in reverse*. So now I've got bignum = [4, 3, 2, 1].

Now you ask me to multiply that by 5. So I create a new, empty vector result=[ ]. I look at the first item in bignum. It's a 4.

4 * 5 is 20, or (as you do at school) it is 0 carry 2. So I push the 0 into result, giving result = [0] and carry = 2.

### Questions for you:

1. If you were doing this by hand (on paper), what would you do next?
2. Why did I decide to store the digits in reverse order?
3. Why did I decide to use a new vector (result), rather than modifying bignum?

and only after you have a worked out how to multiply a bignum by an int:

4. How would you multiply two bignums together?

Comment: I thought a lot about these questions, write down on paper, and finally my code worked as I expected. I'm uploading an answer with the algorithm, I think it's okay now (after a lot of bugfixes). I can't answer your second question, but in my head I know why :D . And if I would modify the bignum itself, it would lead some issues.

Comment: Great! In the solution code you posted I see that you are processing the digits in reverse order. No doubt you've noticed how handling the carry and any new digits is easier that way (which is also the reason the we (as humans) do long division from right to left).

Comment: Now if you read a bignum from text, do one multiplication on it, and then write it out to text, it doesn't matter when you do the reverses. But normally we would read the number once, do *multiple* operations on it, and then write it out once. So we prefer doing the reverse on the read and the write, and keeping the number in its reverse form throughout all the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The solutin for the problem is the follow code. I don't know if I can make this algorithm faster, but it works, so I'm happy with it.

```
BigNumber BigNumber::multiplyBigNumber(BigNumber bn, int num){
    if (num > 0)
  {
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::vector<int> rev = bn.getBigNumber();
    std::reverse(rev.begin(),rev.end());
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<rev.size(); i++){
        result.push_back((rev[i] * num + carry) % 10);
        carry = (rev[i] * num + carry) / 10;
        if(i == rev.size()-1 && carry / 10 == 0 && carry % 10 != 0 ) {
                result.push_back(carry);
                carry = carry / 10;
        }
    }
    while((carry / 10) != 0){
        result.push_back(carry % 10);
        carry /= 10;
        if(carry / 10 == 0) result.push_back(carry);
    }
    std::reverse(result.begin(),result.end());
    bn.setBigNumber(result);
    return bn;
  }else{
    throw TOOSMALL;
  }
}
```